# What does the general solution look like to this homogenous DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Homogenous DE:$$a_0+a_1x\frac{df}{dx}f+a_2x^2\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}+...+a_nx^n\frac{d^nf}{dx^n}=0$$

and can be rearranged to be:$$b_0+b_1x\frac{d}{dx}f+b_2(x\frac{d}{dx})^2f+...+b_n(x\frac{d}{dx})^nf=0$$

Comment: What do you know about Euler differential equations? The substitution $x=e^t$, $u(t)=f(e^t)$, leads to constant coefficients.

Comment: Im thinking its a linear combo of $c_1e^{r_1t}+c_2e^{r_2t}$ based on my knowledge. What's tripping me up is that it's all the way to n.

Comment: You need to handle multiplicities, and you get $n$ roots, counted with multiplicity, and thus $n$ terms of the structure monomial times exponential.